# Adding blocks with jquery(append()) in asp.net mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have troubles with adding blocks with a specific attributes on my asp.net mvc project using jquery.
I need to add block into the page depending on what i have in a dropdownlist(created via c#)
I had created a hidden block in my view(view the code below) wich makes "select" tag with options from my "List"

```
<div id="other" class="EqItem">
   <p>Else: @Html.DropDownList("else", Model.ModEq("",""))</p>
   <p>Serial №: @Html.TextBox("serialelse")</p>
</div>
```

After loading the page i use a function which removes this block from DOM and makes the copy of html code of this block into a variable(blockToAdd )

```
function BlockDelete()
{
    blockToAdd = $("#other").html();
    $("#other").remove();
}
```

then i use this variable to dinamically add blocks into my page(the function below)

```
function ShowListEtc()
{
  for (c = 0; c < 15; c++)
  {
     if (!$("#divotherlist" + c + "").length) {
       id = "divotherlist" + c + "";
       clas = "EqItem";
       blockToAdd = blockToAdd.trim();
       $(".rightside").append('<div id="' + id + '">' + blockToAdd 
            + '<p><img id ="' + id + 'D"src="/Images/delete.png" 
            onclick="Delete(id)"></p></div>');
       $("#" + id).attr('class', clas);
       $("#"+id).show();
       selectid = "othersel" + c;
       $("#" + id).find("select").attr('id', selectid);
       $('#' + selectid + ' option').each(function () { 
          this.setAttribute('id', TransL(this.text) + c); 
          this.setAttribute('onclick', 'MakeNameParent(id)') 
       });
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

The point is that i try to change attributes within created block(append(') but they are not applying!
When i made the code first time, it worked, but suddenly it had stopped to work, then i  tried to use .prepend instead of .append, it began to work for a while but after reopening the project, it had stopped to work again!
Please tell me what i've done incorrect!
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is it doing? I see several things that could be simplified and improved, but I'm not following what the actual problem is. What happens if you just do $(".rightside").append(blockToAdd)?

Comment: append() -adds just div with the markup(which is within the variable "blockToAdd") to div with class "rightside", but i can't set attributes such as css style(for example using attr()) to the added div. Also i need to change the  attributes of the child elements of this added block but i can't

Comment: so...if I understand correctly, append is working, but .attr is not? And how do you know it's not working, what symptoms are you seeing? We really need you to walk us through the details of what you've tried, what you expected to see, and what results you actually saw so we can help track down what's not right.

Comment: Ок. I'am adding the block(<div id="' + id + '">) with the markup(which is within the variable blockToAdd). Then i'm trying to change the class of(<div id="' + id + '">) to ".EqItem" which has property "display:none" and make it visible. Then i want to set "id" to the <select> element which is within the markup of "blockToAdd" also i want to set "id" and "onclick" to all <option> elements in <select>. So i expect to see the added <div id=divotherlist" + c + " class="Eqitem"> which contains <select id="othersel" + c"> which has <opton> elements with their "id's".

Comment: But when i run my project and watch in browser i see my added div(<div id="divotherlist0">) without any attributes(without class="EqItem") and elements <select> and <option> doesn't have any attributes which i've set in jquery function(ShowListEtc())

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding! I've found where i've done a mistake!